# Change Image URL on upload to some random number automatically

Tags: images, permalinks

How to Change Image URL on upload to some random number automatically?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59168/rename-files-on-upload – does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called file renaming on upload.

Here is the URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-renaming-on-upload/

From the settings menu you can set a custom structure.

Comment: Can i also do it without using someplugin